# Failing to use DefineClass (JNI) with a Qt Resource

Tags: c++, qt, java-native-interface, qt-resource

I'm attempting to use **DefineClass** which is part of the [Java Native Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp15986).
The method takes a `const jbyte*` which is a `const signed char*` and I'm trying to parse it from a Qt resource. But there has to be something wrong, as `ExceptionDescribe()` prints **java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file**.

```
QFile qfile(":/SomeClass.class");
qfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly)

QByteArray qbytes = qfile.readAll();
char *test = qbytes.data();
jbyte *buf = reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(test);

jclass processorCls = env->DefineClass("example/SomeClass", nullptr, buf, sizeof(buf)); 

if (env->ExceptionCheck())
{
    env->ExceptionDescribe();
    env->ExceptionClear();
}
```

I can verify that the resource works, as I was able to print the content of the `qfile` with a method found [here](https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Resource_Files.php).

```
void read(QString fName)
{
    QFile file(fName);
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open the file for reading" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    QTextStream in(&file);
    QString text = in.readAll();

    std::cout << text << std::endl;

    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sizeof(buf)` returns the size of the pointer, not the size of the buffer. Please use the `qbytes.size()` instead.